# Problem using procedure pointer in fortran without also using select case logic

Tags: pointers, fortran

Am writing an application where the user is required to enter 4-character text commands to perform the actions of the application. Each command associates with a unique subroutine. I've set the application up so the command text is identical to the associated subroutine name (i.e. user enters 'cmda' and application runs subroutine 'cmda()'. I can get this to work using a select-case statement structure to identify the entered command text and set the procedure pointer to the correct subroutine. However, the application will most likely end up with 50-60 commands and I was hoping to figure out (learn?) an alternative method for setting the procedure pointer directly to avoid such a big select-case structure. Am using gfortran compiler on linux mint.

Appreciate the feedback/comments. Gave me some things to think about. Did come up with a working solution to my problem (see 'FINAL SOLUTION' code below). It involves using the index command to parse a string (CMD_LIST) containing my commands in concatenated form (for validation purposes) and matching the resulting index number to an associated string containing concatenated index numbers (CMD_INDX). Works well and is easy to update with new commands by simply adding the new command, in the appropriate place, to the first string and a new index number to the end of the second. Then adding the sub declaration to cPtr in the appropriate place and the new command subroutine to module command_list.

Working  and non-working examples:

```
! working example (select-case structure)

module command_list

contains

subroutine cmda()
  print *, "execute cmda code"
end subroutine cmda

subroutine cmdb
  print *, "execute cmdb code"
end subroutine cmdb

end module command_list


program execute_subroutine

use command_list

implicit none

! declare pointer to subroutines

character (len=4) :: cInput
procedure (), pointer :: cPointer


! accept command input request from user

do

  write(6,  '("Enter command ? ")', advance="no")
  read(*,"(A)") cInput

  select case (cInput)
    case ("cmda")
      cPointer => cmda
    case ("cmdb")
      cPointer => cmdb
    case default
      stop
  end select

  call cPointer()

end do

end program execute_subroutine


! non-working example (direct assignment)...

module command_list

contains

subroutine cmda()
  print *, "execute cmda code"
end subroutine cmda

subroutine cmdb
  print *, "execute cmdb code"
end subroutine cmdb

end module command_list


program execute_subroutine

use command_list

implicit none

! declare pointer to subroutines

character (len=4) :: cInput
procedure (), pointer :: cPointer


! accept input request from user

do

  write(6,  '("Enter command ? ")', advance="no")
  read(*,"(A)") cInput

  ! this obviously produces an invalid pointer assignment compile error
  cPointer => cInput

  call cPointer()

end do

end program execute_subroutine
```

FINAL SOLUTION...

```
module command_list

contains

subroutine help()
  print *, "execute help code"
end subroutine help

subroutine cmda()
  print *, "execute cmda code"
end subroutine cmda

subroutine cmdb
  print *, "execute cmdb code"
end subroutine cmdb

subroutine quit()
  print *, "execute quit code"
  stop
end subroutine quit

end module command_list

program execute_subroutine

use command_list

implicit none

abstract interface
  subroutine subInterface()
  end subroutine subInterface
end interface

! declare pointer type

type :: subPointer
  procedure(subInterface), nopass, pointer :: subList
end type subPointer

! declare pointer to subroutines

character (len=4) :: cInput
procedure (), pointer :: cPointer
integer :: ptrIndex

! declare pointer array values

type (subPointer) :: cPtr(4)

! declare command verification and associated index strings

character (len=*), parameter :: CMD_LIST = "|help|cmda|cmdb|quit|"
character (len=*), parameter :: CMD_INDX = "|x001|x002|x003|x004|"
integer, parameter :: CMD_LENGTH = 4
integer, parameter :: INDX_OFFSET = 1

integer :: cmdIndex
character (len=4) :: cIndex

! set up pointer array values

cPtr = (/ subPointer(help), subPointer(cmda), subPointer(cmdb), subPointer(quit) /)

! accept input from user (prompt until valid)

do

  write(6,  '("Enter command ? ")', advance="no")
  read(*,"(A)") cInput

  ! verify entered command is valid

  cmdIndex = index(CMD_LIST, trim(adjustl(cInput)))
  if (cmdIndex .gt. 1) then
    
    ! must be valid so get associated index

    cIndex = CMD_INDX(cmdIndex + INDX_OFFSET:cmdIndex + CMD_LENGTH - INDX_OFFSET)
    read(cIndex, *) ptrIndex

    ! execute associated subroutine

    call cPtr(ptrIndex)%subList()

  end if

end do

end program execute_subroutine
```

Comment: You will need to set-up something like this always. Maybe with some array constructor and derived types instead of thes select case, but I do not think you can really avoid the main issue.

Comment: Strictly speaking the linked questions don't exactly answer your question. However, they explain that a whole class of behaviour is not available in Fortran. There are ideas in each about possible ways to implement the type of lookup you are after, but you will have to implement something. If you try and then fail with an approach, please ask a specific question about that, linking here and to the answer you build on.

Comment: Although you say you set up the procedure names to be the same as the "user command" without _reflection_ that just isn't how Fortran works.